# Function file() reads only part of contents in PHP 7.4.27

Tags: php, file, file-get-contents

We have a complex web interface on our dedicated server (Windows Server) which has few console processes with PHP applications running in background and doing various data processing. Some of them write to log files

```
@ file_put_contents( $logsFileNamePath, $fileContents, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX );
```

and there is one console process that analyzes these log files and seeks potential problems, it executes the code below (it can happen in the same time when other console processes write to the log file):

```
$logContent = file( $filePath );
$logContent = array_reverse( $logContent );
//... analyze the content
```

and this has been working fine for years untill recent PHP upgrade from 7.4.20 to 7.4.27 and suddenly sometimes the process that analyzes log files gets **contents** from a log file which is **truncated** in the middle of some line. My suspicion is that there is some internal error in this newer version of PHP that causes this... maybe locking of a file no longer works ? It looks like!
Has anyone of you seen similar problem recently? Do you have any ideas what to do with this? Thanks.

Comment: remove the `@` in front of file_put_contents because it suppresses potential warnings. You might see `file_put_contents(): Exclusive locks may only be set for regular files`.

What is the content of `$logsFileNamePath`?

Comment: What are "regular" files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A patch update from .20 to .27 should not include any backward compatibility breaks, so your experience here is almost certainly just perceptionary.

`LOCK_EX` is advisory, it does not have to be respected, and `file()` does not look at it. It seems pretty clear that your reader is reading before the writer has finished. If you want the reader to respect the lock, you'll have to use identical locking mechanisms (i.e., `fopen()` and `flock()`) in the reader as well:

```
$fp = fopen('/path/to/file', 'r');
flock($fp, LOCK_EX); // this will block until the writer is done
while ($line = fgets($fp)) {
    // process $line
}
fclose($fp);
```

You might also simply update the writer so that it writes to a temp file and then renames it when it's done:

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.temp', $contents);
rename('/path/to/file.temp', '/path/to/file');
```

And then update your reader to expect the file to occasionally be missing:

```
if (!file_exists('/path/to/file')) {
    throw new Exception('Nothing to do.');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned this has been working for YEARS without a problem then suddenly after PHP upgrading it stopped working! WHY? :/

Comment: What do you mean by "LOCK_EX is advisory, it does not have to be respected"? I don't see any such statement in documentation.

Comment: The PHP upgrade is probably not the change that broke this functionality. With the code you posted, you should have never had a lock to start with, you were just getting lucky. Perhaps your file sizes are getting larger and/or the CPU is getting more strained, increasing the chances of a conflict. <shrug> It doesn't matter much, the fix is trivial.

Comment: From the `flock()` docs: "PHP supports a portable way of locking complete files in an advisory way (which means all accessing programs have to use the same way of locking or it will not work)."

Comment: The system operates the same as before. Log file sizes didn't change and CPU has the same work to do. And it IS important for me why this thing stopped working.

Comment: Also, my writer only APPENDs lines at the end of log files. It does not rewrite entire files, so why would reader suddenly read these files as being truncated in middle of some line in middle of a file? Doesn't make sence to me. I don't think that changing implementation would fix anything here.

Comment: OK I changed implementation of my reader as proposed and it works so far! I didn't expect that. Still not sure what caused that problem though. I think it's either PHP upgrade or maybe some Windows update - something that changed some internal mechanism of dealing with locking files.